# Additions of two string values in php

Tags: php, addition

I want to plus or Additions of two values in Php.

```
$myvalue = "$10.00"+"$10";
```

I want this output:-

```
"$20.00";
```

I just want to plus these values. I am getting this values from somewhere, i just want to plus or additions of these values. 
I am new two php.Please some body let me know what we have to do to achieve this in php.

Comment: really you need to ask question for addition

Comment: Do you get these values as strings? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: `$myvalue = (10.00 + 10); print $myvalue;`

Comment: A `$` sign is not part of a number: `$myvalue = 10.00+10; echo '$' . number_format($myvalue, 2);`

Comment: `$a = 10.00; $b = 10; print ($a + $b);`

Comment: `$a = 10.00; $b = 10; print "$".($a + $b);`

Comment: The issue is that you are trying to add two strings, not numbers.

Comment: @Eugen Why don't you post your comments as an answer and stop cluttering the comments section?

Comment: @Tim Lewis: i don't need to get points for so simply answers!

Comment: @Eugen And we don't need 3 comments from you :P But w/e

Comment: Your question is unclear as to exactly how the values are submitted. You need to modify your question in that regard. Plus, why should this be any relation to cakephp? This is just standard PHP. Remove the tag if there's no relevance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $val1 = "$10.00";
    $val2 = "$10";

    $myvalue = ltrim($val1, "$") + ltrim($val2, "$");
    echo "$" . number_format((float)$myvalue, 2, ".", "");

?>
```

Output:

```
$20.00
```

And if you have only 1 string this should work:

```
<?php

    $string = "$10.00 + $10";

    $values = preg_split("/(\+)/", $string);
    array_walk($values, function(&$value) { 
        $value = ltrim(trim($value), "$");
    }, $values); 

    $myvalue = 0;

    foreach($values as $value)
        $myvalue += $value;

    echo "$" . number_format((float)$myvalue, 2, ".", "");

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$myvalue = 10.00 + 10;

echo number_format((float)$myvalue, 2, '.', '');
```

Comment: The problem with your question is that you are adding two strings, you need to add the two numbers first and then precede it with the $ sign (dollar sign).

Comment: I am getting values like this :- "$10.00"+"$10" in string format .

Comment: Is the user typing in the $-sign?

Comment: @RavinderSinghBhawer Do you get the values like in my answer? like in 2 variables or in one?

Comment: no , There are some predefine functions of woocommerce plugin . they return values like this . i just want to plus these values .

Comment: This answer isn't wrong per say, it just doesn't address how to add the numbers when they aren't ints to begin with.

Comment: I answered the question before the OP mentioned what format the strings were being inputted as.

Answer (score 0):

If you get string with dollar you can remove it with [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) before doing your addition :

```
$value1 = "$10.00";
$value2 = "$10";

$result = substr($value1, 1) + substr($value2, 1);
var_dump($result) // float(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition of two string or integer is done by PHP itself. You have to replace all non numerical character except '.(dot)' from string.

**Example:**

```
$myvalue = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', "$10.00") + preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', "$10");
echo '$'.$myvalue."\n"; 
echo '$'.number_format($myvalue, 2, '.', '')."\n"; #for floating point
```

For **'$10.00+$10'**:

```
$myvalue = eval('return ' . preg_replace('/[^0-9.+]/', '', '$10.00+$10') . ';');
echo '$'.$myvalue."\n";
echo '$'.number_format($myvalue, 2, '.', '')."\n"; #for floating point
```